# How to get number of TestNG threads at runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I am running tests with TestNG but I want to dynamically limit the load on the tested server.
To do that, I would like to verify at runtime that I am not sending more than X requests per second to the server, and if I am above, then have the thread to sleep.

My question is: how can I get the number of threads at runtime?

I was looking into ITestContext but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Are you actually running your threads in parallel? If not the it will be always 1 :-)

Comment: Yes, I am running testng from eclipse and 10 threads are running

Comment: Hm if getting the total number of threads with java.lang.Thread.activeCount() is for some reason not enough (tested methods spawn new threads or smth?) maybe trying to get the count of the ThreadGroup related to the TestNG testing thread will work? But then again that thread spawns the tested threads so it would result in a similar problem.

Comment: java.lang.Thread.activeCount() gives the total number of threads,  not the number of testNG threads.

Comment: yes that's what I wrote. But when you are running tests the only threads you will have are the test threads. If some tested methods will spawn new threads they will be in the same threadgroup.

Comment: also as I mentioned you can try playing around with ThreadGroup, check in which group TestNG tests are running and maybe with that extract the number of TestNG threads but I'm not sure if they won't be in the same threadgroup with some other threads. This would complicate things even more.

Answer (score 3):

Within your running TestNG tagged test, Thread.activeCount() gives you the number of threads just in your current TestNG group. If your threadPoolSize is set to 1, this number will be 1. If your threadPoolSize is greater than 1, this number will be threadPoolSize + 1, because there is also a TestNG manager thread in addition to the pool size. For threads that you create on the fly, you need to construct them passing in your TestNG ThreadGroup. Example:

```
    Thread aNewWorkerThread = new Thread( Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup(), yourRunnableThingHere );
```

Those threads, when active, should then be reflected in your Thread.activeCount() return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject "IInvokedMethod method" of TestNg and then use the following code

```
 int count = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getThreadCount();
```